Cannot change ownership of elasticsearch directory in colab
I was trying to install elastic search in Google Colab (following this article - https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/io/blob/master/docs/tutorials/elasticsearch.ipynb), and it seems that to run the service, you need to change the ownership to a user that is not root. I tried the chown command for this and then did an ls -l but don't see the ownership change.
In fact, when I use the verbose option with chown I can see the logs showing the permission change from root:root to daemon:daemon.
!chown -R -v daemon:daemon elasticsearch-8.15.0/

Following is a snippet of the output illustrating the above
changed ownership of 'elasticsearch-8.15.0/lib/elasticsearch-8.15.0.jar' from root:root to daemon:daemon
changed ownership of 'elasticsearch-8.15.0/lib/elasticsearch-preallocate-8.15.0.jar' from root:root to daemon:daemon
changed ownership of 'elasticsearch-8.15.0/lib/elasticsearch-x-content-8.15.0.jar' from root:root to daemon:daemon
changed ownership of 'elasticsearch-8.15.0/lib/elasticsearch-lz4-8.15.0.jar' from root:root to daemon:daemon
changed ownership of 'elasticsearch-8.15.0/lib/elasticsearch-cli-8.15.0.jar' from root:root to daemon:daemon
changed ownership of 'elasticsearch-8.15.0/lib/elasticsearch-simdvec-8.15.0.jar' from root:root to daemon:daemon
changed ownership of 'elasticsearch-8.15.0/lib/elasticsearch-native-8.15.0.jar' from root:root to daemon:daemon
changed ownership of 'elasticsearch-8.15.0/lib/elasticsearch-core-8.15.0.jar' from root:root to daemon:daemon
changed ownership of 'elasticsearch-8.15.0/lib/elasticsearch-logging-8.15.0.jar' from root:root to daemon:daemon
changed ownership of 'elasticsearch-8.15.0/lib/elasticsearch-secure-sm-8.15.0.jar' from root:root to daemon:daemon
changed ownership of 'elasticsearch-8.15.0/lib/elasticsearch-geo-8.15.0.jar' from root:root to daemon:daemon
changed ownership of 'elasticsearch-8.15.0/lib/elasticsearch-plugin-analysis-api-8.15.0.jar' from root:root to daemon:daemon
changed ownership of 'elasticsearch-8.15.0/lib/elasticsearch-plugin-api-8.15.0.jar' from root:root to daemon:daemon
changed ownership of 'elasticsearch-8.15.0/lib/elasticsearch-grok-8.15.0.jar' from root:root to daemon:daemon
changed ownership of 'elasticsearch-8.15.0/lib/elasticsearch-tdigest-8.15.0.jar' from root:root to daemon:daemon

But doing an ls -l still shows root as the owner and group.
!ls -l elasticsearch-8.15.0/


total 2273
drwx------  2 root root    4096 Aug 11 13:44 bin
drwx------  3 root root    4096 Aug 11 13:45 config
drwx------  8 root root    4096 Aug  5 10:11 jdk
drwx------  6 root root    4096 Aug  5 10:11 lib
-rwx------  1 root root    3860 Aug  5 10:04 LICENSE.txt
drwx------  2 root root    4096 Aug  5 10:07 logs
drwx------ 83 root root    4096 Aug  5 10:12 modules
-rwx------  1 root root 2285006 Aug  5 10:07 NOTICE.txt
drwx------  2 root root    4096 Aug  5 10:07 plugins
-rwx------  1 root root    9111 Aug  5 10:04 README.asciidoc

PS - Since this is a colab question as well as a linux question, I wasn't sure whether to ask this here or on the unix/linux forum (https://unix.stackexchange.com/). Please let me know if this is the wrong place.
